# Доступ через This. Почему не работает код?

Tags: javascript, this

Отрывок из книги:

```
window.color = "red";
var о = {
    color: "Bluе"
};

function sayColor() {
    alert(this.color);
}
sayColor(); // " red"
o.sayColor = sayColor;
o.sayColor(); // " Bluе"
```

Функция `sayColor( )` здесь определена глобально, но ссылается на объект this. Значение this не определяется вплоть до вызова функции, поэтому при выполнении
кода оно может изменяться.

Когда функция `sayColor( )` вызывается в глобаьной
области видимости, она выводит строку "red", потому что this указывает на объект window, то есть значение `this.color` эквивалентно `window.color`.

Когда после
назначения функции объекту `о` вызывается функция `о.sayColor( )`, объект this
указывает на о и свойство `this.color` интерпретируется как `о.color`, в результате выводится строка "Bluе".

Comment: Вопрос вызван **проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой**. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) до публикации вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

переменная var 0 -  у вас на русском, переименуйте на английский

Comment: уволенный девелопер передает привет :)

Comment: не понял про что вы)

Comment: видимо @ikar теперь ищет работу

Comment: @heff, есть байка про то, что обиженные девелоперы перед уходом оставляют такие штуки в коде

Comment: Чтобы оставить такую штуку надо ещё и тестов к этому модулю забайпассить..

Comment: Это если вообще есть тесты

Comment: Не понял? Этот код и текст отрывок из книги....

Comment: книгу кто то переводил, и не всегда этим занимаются программисты, переводчик как увидел так и написал

Comment: спасибо за ответы. У меня вновь непонятки, почему в консоль записывается undefined если изменить код на вот так: console.log(sayColor());

Comment: потому что функция sayColor ничего не возвращает, а вы написали - выведи мне то что вернет функция sayColor

Comment: ох уж этот JS, с return - возвращает результат работы, без него, если есть просто вызов sayColor(); то, тоже будет результат. Когда же всё это правильно упакуется в голове..накипело)

Comment: по мне так все логично, если функция ничего не возвращает, то и нечего выводить. Если вам нужно код функции в консоль вывести пишите там - console.log(sayColor);